# AWS CDK: cannot find Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm learning AWS CDK.  I'm trying to deploy a program that uses aws-sdk but my program cannot find the aws-sdk.  It IS installed.

```
$ ls -ld ./node_modules/*aws*
drwxrwxr-x   5 jimbo jimbo 87 Jul 11 13:04 ./node_modules/@aws-cdk
drwxrwxr-x   5 jimbo jimbo 180 Jul 11 13:04 ./node_modules/aws-cdk
drwxrwxr-x 264 jimbo jimbo 12288 Jul 11 13:04 ./node_modules/aws-cdk-lib
drwxrwxr-x   9 jimbo jimbo 4096 Jul 11 14:23 ./node_modules/aws-sdk

$ npm install aws-sdk
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

added 28 packages, and audited 372 packages in 3s

46 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

It's listed in my packages.json

```
  "name": "cdk-quotes-api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "cdk-quotes-api": "bin/cdk-quotes-api.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/node": "20.1.7",
    "aws-cdk": "2.87.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.87.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1414.0",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```

What I get:

```
Response
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/app.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/app.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:997:17)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1195:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1201:1"
  ]
}

Function Logs
2023-07-11T18:17:03.923Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/app.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'","Require stack:","- /var/task/app.js","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:997:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1195:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1201:1"]}
2023-07-11T18:17:05.511Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/app.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'","Require stack:","- /var/task/app.js","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:997:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1032:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1195:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1201:1"]}
START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.ImportModuleError
END RequestId: 
REPORT RequestId:
```

Duration: 1815.30 ms    Billed Duration: 1816 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 17 MB

Do you have any ideas?

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you seem to be constructing the most recent Lambda Function, [Node.js 18.x runtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-18-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/). Node.js 18.x runtime includes AWS SDK for JavaScript v3, that imports quite diferent modules like `@aws-sdk/client-s3`, `@aws-sdk/client-sqs`, etc.

ex:

```
import { SendMessageCommand, SQSClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-sqs'
import {
  Context,
  S3Event,
  SQSEvent,
} from 'aws-lambda'


const sqsClient = new SQSClient({})

export const handler = async (event: SQSEvent, context: Context) => {

  const sqsMessages = event.Records
  const batchItemFailures: { itemIdentifier: string }[] = []

  try {
    for (const message of sqsMessages) {
      const s3Event: S3Event = JSON.parse(message.body)
      const messageId = message.messageId

      // logic
    }
    return ({
      statusCode: 200,
      batchItemFailures: batchItemFailures,
    })
  } catch (err) {
    return ({
      body: err,
      statusCode: 500,
      batchItemFailures: event.Records.map(e => ({ itemIdentifier: e.messageId })),
    })
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider downgrading to [Node.js 16.x runtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-16-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/), then the `aws-sdk` module will be present there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was using node 18 and aws-sdk 2.  I had to drop back to node 16 to make my code work.  I think going to aws-sdk 3 might have worked as well, but that required change to the code.  I've also found that Python 3.6 is problematic.  Python 3.8 seems to work better.

Comment: Is this actually different from the answer @Vasyl Herman gave?